# How does an object work as input attribute in React.js

Tags: html, reactjs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGqrE.png)

This I understand it works without any issues but...

what I don't understand is that if I pass in an object as a prop to a component (which is its child) and use spread operator to extract its properties in the  field, how does it work? How do those properties become input tag's attributes?
[Adding HTML properties to input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXLVd.png)
[Adding an object as an attribute to input element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAnlB.png)

Furthermore, if I try to do it by myself it shows me an error
[Adding Input tag's attribute as an object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bb99Z.png)

Comment: You are asking a few questions here, and several of the things you imply are the same are in fact very different. Also, please include each of your code examples as text, rather than images.

Comment: Please read [ask]

Answer (score -1):

I guess you can use like this

```js
const Input = ({label,id,input}) => {
    return (
        <div className={styles.input}>
            <label htmlFor={id} className={styles.label}>{label}</label>
            <input {...input}/>
        </div>
    )
}
const MealItemForm = ({id})=>{
    return (
        <form>
            <Input label="Amount" id={`amount_${id}`} input={{
                type:"number",
                min:"1",
                ...
            }}/>
        </form>
    )
}
```

Comment: The question is asking for explanations. Your answer lacks any.

Comment: I've already done it that way please look at both the pics after the question (How do those properties become input tag's attributes?)..
My question is why does it happen that way?
How can an object be used as an attribute to the input tag ?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).